# How to replace OR operator with UNION operator?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    h.id,
    h.subject,
    h.body matnF,
    h.amount,
    h.keywords tags,
    h.closed,
    h.author_id author,
    h.AcceptedAnswer,
    h.type,
    h.visibility,
    h.date_time,
    v.value AS vote_value,
    u.reputation,
    u.user_fname,
    u.user_lname,
    u.avatar,
    (h.author_id = user_id1) as hasUserId,
    (select COALESCE(sum(vv.value), 0)
     from votes vv
     where h.id = vv.post_id and vv.table_code = '$this->table_code'
    ) as total_votes,
    (select count(1)
     from favorites ff
     where h.type = 0 and h.id = ff.post_id and ff.table_code = '$this- >table_code'
    ) as total_favorites,
    CASE WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
         WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = :user_id2 THEN '1'
    ELSE EXISTS( select 1
            from money m
            where m.user_id = :user_id3 and m.post_id = h.id
           )END paid,
    CASE WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2'
    ELSE '3'
    END AS favorite
FROM qanda h
LEFT JOIN votes v ON h.id = v.post_id AND v.user_id = :user_id4 AND   v.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON h.type = 0 AND h.id = f.post_id AND f.user_id = :user_id5 AND f.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN users u ON h.author_id = u.id and h.visibility = 1
WHERE h.id = :id1 OR h.related = :id2
ORDER BY h.type , h.AcceptedAnswer DESC , h.date_time
LIMIT 20;
```

Please focus on this line of query above:

```
WHERE h.id = :id1 OR h.related = :id2
```

As you see, there is `OR` logical operator between those two conditions. As you know, `OR` usually prevents effective use of indexes. So when there is huge data, the performance of my query is really weak.

How can I improve it? Actually I'm trying to replace `OR` with `UNION`, but as you see my query is too long .. So is there any idea?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the result of `EXPLAIN`: *(for a really short dataset -- overall 20 rows in)*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would try is a subquery:

```
from ((select q.* from quanda q where q.id = :id1) union
      (select q.* from quanda q where q.related = :id2)
     ) left join
     . . .
```

Note:  This really wants indexes on `quanda(id)` and `quanda(related)` for performance.

If few rows are selected, then this might be much faster.

Comment: But what happens to `WHERE` clause in my query? And also yes, usually few rows are selected *(5 row maximum)* ..! May you please apply your idea on my original query and add it to your answer?

Comment: @Stack . . . You would remove the `where` clause.  It is redundant because it is in the subquery.

Comment: Yes you are right ..! But I don't think using `UNION` make anything better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729731/can-mysql-use-indexes-when-there-is-or-between-conditions

Answer (score 1):

You may give it a try:

```
SELECT h.id, h.subject, h.body matnF, h.amount, h.keywords tags, h.closed, h.author_id author, h.AcceptedAnswer, h.type, h.visibility, h.date_time, v.value AS vote_value, u.reputation, u.user_fname, u.user_lname, u.avatar, (h.author_id = :user_id1) as hasUserId,
(select COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0) from votes vv where h.id = vv.post_id and vv.table_code = '$this->table_code') as total_votes,
(select count(1) from favorites ff where h.type = 0 and h.id = ff.post_id and ff.table_code = '$this->table_code') as total_favorites,
CASE WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = :user_id2 THEN '1'
ELSE EXISTS (select 1 from money m where m.user_id = :user_id3 and m.post_id = h.id) END paid,
CASE WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2' ELSE '3' END AS favorite
FROM qanda h
LEFT JOIN votes v ON h.id = v.post_id AND v.user_id = :user_id4 AND v.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON h.type = 0 AND h.id = f.post_id AND f.user_id = :user_id5 AND f.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN users u ON h.author_id = u.id and h.visibility = 1
WHERE h.id = :id1 
ORDER BY h.type, /*(tans.id IS NOT NULL) DESC,*/ h.AcceptedAnswer DESC, h.date_time
LIMIT 20

UNION 

SELECT 
*
FROM 
(SELECT h.id, h.subject, h.body matnF, h.amount, h.keywords tags, h.closed, h.author_id author, h.AcceptedAnswer, h.type, h.visibility, h.date_time, v.value AS vote_value, u.reputation, u.user_fname, u.user_lname, u.avatar, (h.author_id = :user_id1) as hasUserId,
(select COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0) from votes vv where h.id = vv.post_id and vv.table_code = '$this->table_code') as total_votes,
(select count(1) from favorites ff where h.type = 0 and h.id = ff.post_id and ff.table_code = '$this->table_code') as total_favorites,
CASE WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = :user_id2 THEN '1'
ELSE EXISTS (select 1 from money m where m.user_id = :user_id3 and m.post_id = h.id) END paid,
CASE WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2' ELSE '3' END AS favorite
FROM qanda h
LEFT JOIN votes v ON h.id = v.post_id AND v.user_id = :user_id4 AND v.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON h.type = 0 AND h.id = f.post_id AND f.user_id = :user_id5 AND f.table_code = '$this->table_code'
LEFT JOIN users u ON h.author_id = u.id and h.visibility = 1
WHERE h.id = :id2 
ORDER BY h.type, /*(tans.id IS NOT NULL) DESC,*/ h.AcceptedAnswer DESC, h.date_time
LIMIT 20) t;
```

**Note:** Replace `UNION` by `UNION ALL` if you want to allow duplicates in your final result set.

Comment: Yes this work. I tested it already .. Just you know, that scares me .. My original query is too long and yours is **really really** too long `:-)` .. I prefer don't use it. thank you anyway.

Comment: the number of characters in query actually gets doubled if you want to adopt `UNION` instead of omitting `OR` logic.

Comment: You may give a try using `IN` like `WHERE h.id IN (:id1,:id2)....`. And check the `EXPLAIN` result.

Comment: I did .. it gets better, but not much ..! Still it's slow for huge data.

Comment: `UNION` makes is much faster ..! Actually I tested it before asking. But as you see if I want to use UNION the query will be really big .. Gordon's approach seems nice too, I have not yet decided which to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to get any advantage from using a UNION instead of an OR then make that portion of the query as tiny as it can be, in particular keep the number of columns to a minimum. Do the union before any other joins. I suggest this:

```
SELECT
      h.id
    , h.subject
    , h.body      AS matnF
    , h.amount
    , h.keywords  AS tags
    , h.closed
    , h.author_id AS author
    , h.AcceptedAnswer
    , h.type
    , h.visibility
    , h.date_time
    , v.value     AS vote_value
    , u.reputation
    , u.user_fname
    , u.user_lname
    , u.avatar
    , h.author_id AS hasUserId
    , (     SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vv.value), 0)
            FROM votes vv
            WHERE h.id = vv.post_id
                  AND vv.table_code = '$this->table_code'
      )  AS total_votes
    , (     SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM favorites ff
            WHERE h.type = 0 AND h.id = ff.post_id
                  AND ff.table_code = '$this- >table_code'
      ) AS total_favorites
    , CASE
            WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2'
            ELSE '3'
      END  AS favorite
    , CASE
            WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
            WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = :user_id2 THEN '1'
            ELSE EXISTS( select 1
                from money m
                where m.user_id = :user_id3 and m.post_id = h.id
               )
      END paid
FROM (
      SELECT q.id , q.author_id , q.visibility , q.type FROM quanda q WHERE q.id = :id1
      UNION
      SELECT q.id , q.author_id , q.visibility , q.type FROM quanda q WHERE q.related = :id2
      ) h
      LEFT JOIN votes v ON h.id = v.post_id
                  AND v.user_id = :user_id4
                  AND v.table_code = '$this->table_code'
      LEFT JOIN favorites f ON h.type = 0
                  AND h.id = f.post_id
                  AND f.user_id = :user_id5
                  AND f.table_code = '$this->table_code'
      LEFT JOIN users u ON h.author_id = u.id
                  AND h.visibility = 1
```

Comment: Note this is similar to the recommendation by Gordon Linoff except I would not recommend use of `select *`

Comment: By the way, I also suggest you look at those correlated subqueries in the select clause they can be a cause of performance issues.

Comment: Do you mean those parentheses?

Comment: e.g. this is one of the correlated subqueries `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vv.value), 0)
            FROM votes vv
            WHERE h.id = vv.post_id
                  AND vv.table_code = '$this->table_cod`

Comment: I just said "look at" or "consider" each of those because they MIGHT BE a cause of slowness. Note I am not suggesting my query is perfect just that IF you are to get advantage from a union make the column list as short as possible I think I missed some column you may need in the outer query.

Comment: Got it .. thx again .. And yes you're missing some columns to select in inner query and also that `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` .. However it doesn't matter. I got it idea ..

Comment: By the way why `WHERE` clause is still there? Seems useless to me. Am I right?